# DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity query

Tags: entity-framework

I am using framework 4.5 with EF5 Database first for an existing database that does not have identity insert switched on for most tables. The database I'm using also has existing data. i am trying to switch on Database Generated identities.

EF5 did it thing and the map for my entity shows

```
this.Property(t => t.ActionId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

I have updated to

```
this.Property(t => t.ActionId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

I ran Update-Database -Verbose and it says:

```
No pending code-based migrations.
Applying automatic migration: 201304151128390_AutomaticMigration.
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Action] ALTER COLUMN [ActionId] [int] NOT NULL
```

If I open the table designer in SqlMS, Identity Specification is still set to No. I have checked my database connection and  can add a new column to the same table. I have also tried swapping to a data annotations with no joy:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

Am I missing a step?

Thanks in advance
Rob

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with my code, then found offer to use 
 [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)], but this still did not helped me.
After this steps, I left [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] annotation for my key property and have set Identity Specification manually to yes, and increment by 1. I it worked.
I come to opinion that this might be a bug in asp.net

Answer (score -1):

you can get your goal by droping your database and re execute the Update-Database -Verbose Command in Package Console Manager.

Comment: This feels like an answer to another question.